# Is elliptic curves an group object in some category？

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, elliptic-curves

Is elliptic curves an group object in some category？

Group like object, like lie group,formal group, algebraic group,topological group, is sometimes  define as group object in some category.
What about elliptic curves？

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elliptic+curve#OverGeneralRingConceptualDefinition

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed elliptic curve, it is an abelian variety, which is a group scheme, so it is a group object in $(Sch)$.

Comment: This is not strictly correct. Typically one works with group schemes over some base scheme, and these are group objects not in the category of schemes but rather the slice over the base scheme.

Comment: Yes you are right, I should point out what is the base scheme (for fixed elliptic curve), and elliptic curve is the group object in the category over base scheme.

Comment: You can and should add that material to your answer via an edit.